# Does partitioning in mysql create tables or merely virtual tables?

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

When a partition is done in mysql , does it create tables or does it create virtual tables (i.e. views) which are pretty much stored queries accessed by a table name?

Here is an example (although in Oracle, this is just used as an example - I am most curious about how it is handled in mysql) from http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Oracle/Partitioning-in-Oracle/1/:

```
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE_ORDERS
(ORDER_NUMBER NUMBER,
ORDER_DATE DATE,
CUST_NUM NUMBER,
TOTAL_PRICE NUMBER,
TOTAL_TAX NUMBER,
TOTAL_SHIPPING NUMBER)
PARTITION BY RANGE(ORDER_DATE)
(
PARTITION SO99Q1 VALUES LESS THAN TO_DATE(‘01-APR-1999’, ‘DD-MON-YYYY’),
PARTITION SO99Q2 VALUES LESS THAN TO_DATE(‘01-JUL-1999’, ‘DD-MON-YYYY’),
PARTITION SO99Q3 VALUES LESS THAN TO_DATE(‘01-OCT-1999’, ‘DD-MON-YYYY’),
PARTITION SO99Q4 VALUES LESS THAN TO_DATE(‘01-JAN-2000’, ‘DD-MON-YYYY’),
PARTITION SO00Q1 VALUES LESS THAN TO_DATE(‘01-APR-2000’, ‘DD-MON-YYYY’),
PARTITION SO00Q2 VALUES LESS THAN TO_DATE(‘01-JUL-2000’, ‘DD-MON-YYYY’),
PARTITION SO00Q3 VALUES LESS THAN TO_DATE(‘01-OCT-2000’, ‘DD-MON-YYYY’),
PARTITION SO00Q4 VALUES LESS THAN TO_DATE(‘01-JAN-2001’, ‘DD-MON-YYYY’)
)
;
```

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Comment: @marc_s - I didn't realize that different vendors took different approaches to partitioning, sorry. I would be most interested in MySQL and will update the question.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Mysql 5.6 Reference Manual (16.1 Overview of Partitioning in MySQL):

> Partitioning takes this notion a step further, by enabling you to
>   distribute portions of individual tables across a file system
>   according to rules which you can set largely as needed. In effect,
>   **different portions of a table are stored as separate tables** in
>   different locations.

Comment: Yes, I have read that entire manual. However, what I took issue with in that line was the `In effect` portion. It is a rather vague way to start that sentence and made it hard to interpret weather or not the table partitioned was still around, and so were a group of other partition tables. Or, if the table partitioned was no longer present and instead replaced with a group of "partition" tables. Or, if the table was still there, there were in fact no other tables, and the partitions represented virtual tables.