# How do different SQL vendors approach partitioning?

Tags: sql, database-partitioning

What are the different approaches taken by vendors when implementing partitioning in a database?

This is response to marc_s's comment here: [Does partitioning in mysql create tables or merely virtual tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10035498/1026459)

Answers in the form of a link to a good book accepted :)

Comment: To the person who downvoted / chose to vote to close: If every vendor approaches partitioning differently, then why is this not a valid question?

Comment: It wasn't me :-) just trying to understand. Maybe it's not so much that it's not a valid question; first of all, this is on the edge of being no longer programming-related (it's really more of a database architectural question --> better off on dba.stackexchange.com), and second of all, it's a fairly broad question - you could write entire **books** on that topic! So maybe that's why someone deemed this question *overly broad* for this site

Comment: @marc_s - Editted question to allow for the inclusion of books :)

Answer (score 1):

I can only speak about **SQL Server**:

**Every partition is a new b-tree internally.** The query processor creates the illusion to have one gigantic table. It has little optimizations which take into account that the table is partitioned because the partitioning itself is largely **transparent** to the optimizer: A partitioned table on column P with clustered index on (A, B) appears (performance wise) as a single table having the clustering key (P, A, B). This is true for seeks and scans.

Having partitions be a new internal table makes **bulk operations** on whole partitions **easy**: just drop the partition or create a new one. You can even swap partitions with unrelated tables if the schema is exactly identical! (ALTER TABLE SWITCH PARTITION)

Having partitions be b-trees has implications for maintenance: You can place individual partitions on **different drives**, or make them read-only and **exclude them from backups**.

Answer (score 1):

You can mimic partitioning by using:

- a set of tables named with some pattern as partitions;
- a view on top of them to hide the structure of the data storage and present it as a single relation;
- application integrated logic: make application aware bout the partitioning model and thus using the right tables to perform DDL statements.

This approach had been in use with ORACLE 7.2 (I might be wrong bout the version, too many years) and can be implemented in any database that supports views. If views are not there, you can create a special function/class within application that will mimic view behavior.

Still, it is quite complicated and error-prone approach as storage layout is visible outside the database. So, if possible, go for a native or isolated partitioning.

ORACLE supports partitioning on the database level as of 8th version, making storage layout completely hidden outside the database.

Although PostgreSQL has no built-in partitioning support yet, this is a [work in progress now](http://postgresql.uservoice.com/forums/21853-general/suggestions/269812-oracle-style-table-partitioning). Also, PostgreSQL already has a set of useful features that make it possible to make database-only partitioning, hiding implementation from any external users. You can check details [here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Table_partitioning).